# 4 fragments in one layout

Tags: android, layout, fragment

i want to show 4 fragments on 1 screen . As four of them rectangular shaped .

xml code is

shown below

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:weightSum="4" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="2"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:paddingBottom="15dp"
    android:paddingTop="25dp"
    android:weightSum="2" >

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/fragment1"
        android:name="frags"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_weight="1.00" >
    </fragment>

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/fragment2"
        android:name="frags"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="2"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:paddingBottom="25dp"
    android:weightSum="2" >

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/fragment3"
        android:name="frags"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/fragment4"
        android:name="frags"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" />
</LinearLayout>
```

although i know how to make four differnt fragments in four different layouts and four classes and then link them in main activity by fragment adapter in  **tabular screen** or **View Pager**
but i dont know how how to initialise four of them in **main activity** , as the 4 of the fragments are appear on 1 screen in squarical manner without  overlapping each other . Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot of the actual resulting view? I guess your `weight` are wrong.

Comment: yes offcourse [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/g1838qeascrdjfq/Capture.JPG?dl=0)

Comment: i just need to know how can i display all of them in this manner on Main screen of my application .

Comment: @abhifreak check the updated ans

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can take 4 frame layout as a container and replace it with fragment.

```
frame_fragment_four.xml

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:weightSum="4" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="2"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:paddingBottom="15dp"
    android:paddingTop="25dp"
    android:weightSum="2" >

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/fragment1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_weight="1.00" >
    </FrameLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/fragment2"
        android:name="frags"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="2"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:paddingBottom="25dp"
    android:weightSum="2" >

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/fragment3"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/fragment4"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" />
</LinearLayout>
```

In Fragment Activity replace fragment

```
    public class MainBaseFragmentActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle arg0) {
        super.onCreate(arg0);
        setContentView(R.layout.frame_fragment_four);
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.fragment1, new FragmentScreenA()).commit();
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.fragment2, new FragmentScreenB()).commit();
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.fragment3, new FragmentScreenC()).commit();
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.fragment4, new FragmentScreenD()).commit();
    }

}
```

"as the 4 of the fragments are appear on 1 screen in squarical manner without overlapping each other ."

[image]

Share or post  if i gt it wrong ..

Comment: thanks !! never thought of replacing Frame layout , can we do this for some other layouts ??

Comment: ok yes we can but AFAIK for fragment display and replacement and all frame layout is the correct and proper view which u can use as a container.

Comment: sorry i'm a newbie just started with fragments , so if i need to add any element in any of fragment like fragment A like button , textview , so how can i do it dynamically ? or we can add it through xml ?